# Spring oAuth: customization of request to generate oauth token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

I would like to get a code example of how I can customize the request for the token generation, since I currently get the grant_type through form-data and I would like to receive it through the body JSON type.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RTlP.png)

I am using a Spring Security authorization server.

I have tried to add configuration to add TokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter but I have not found the right solution, thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.